# Why am I getting this parse error in a PHP if statement?

Tags: php, parse-error, control-structure

I am getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!=' (T_IS_NOT_EQUAL) in C:\xampp\htdocs\assurance\confirmation.php on line 131

Here is lines 131-134 of my code:

```
if ($_POST['password']) != ($_POST['confirm'])  { 
echo '<p class="error">Your passwords do not match.</p>';
$okay = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Remove the extra parentheses. Your code should be: `if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm'])`.

Comment: `if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm'])`

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm'])  { 
echo '<p class="error">Your passwords do not match.</p>';
$okay = FALSE;
}
```

the syntax of the if statement is

```
if (expr)
  statement
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm'])  { 
    echo '<p class="error">Your passwords do not match.</p>';
    $okay = FALSE;
}
```